# Facebook api with monotouch

Tags: c#, facebook, binding, xamarin.ios

I'm having troubles using the facebook binding from here ( https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/facebook ) and the problem is that the authorize ( login ) function doesn't work on the device.  On the simulator it's working perfect, but from the device instead of the webbrowser login window it launches the official facebook app ( installed on the phone ).

The same thing happens with the sample provided with the binding.

Any ideeas how can I use the browser to login ( if I unninstall the official facebook app it works ok on the device also ) instead of the facebook app?

The code I use:

```
class SessionDelegate : FBSessionDelegate
{
    AppDelegate container;
    NSAction onLogin;

    public NSAction OnLogin {
        get {
            return this.onLogin;
        }
        set {
            onLogin = value;
        }
    }       

    public SessionDelegate (AppDelegate container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public override void DidNotLogin (bool cancelled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("did not login");
        //container.SaveAuthorization ();
        if( OnLogin != null ) OnLogin.Invoke();
    }

    public override void DidLogin ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("login !");
        container.SaveAuthorization ();
        if( OnLogin != null ) OnLogin.Invoke();
    }

    public override void DidLogout ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("logout !");
        container.ClearAuthorization();
    }
}
```

And:

```
var sessionDelegate = new SessionDelegate (this); 
facebook            = new Facebook (LocalSettings.FacebookAppId, sessionDelegate);
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
if (defaults ["FBAccessTokenKey"] != null && defaults ["FBExpirationDateKey"] != null)
{
         facebook.AccessToken    = defaults ["FBAccessTokenKey"] as NSString;
         facebook.ExpirationDate = defaults ["FBExpirationDateKey"] as NSDate;
}
```

and for login:

```
facebook.Authorize(new string [] { "email", "publish_stream", "read_friendlists", "user_photos" });
```

Comment: If I had to guess, this is the way their library is intended to work.  Does it not login for you?

Comment: No it doesen't. And it cames back in my app calling the "DidNotLogin" function from de FBSessionDelegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answer myself.  The problem was in the facebook developer app settings, the iOS Bundle ID didn't was the same with the one in monodevelop identifier :)

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is the developer's intend. First I don't understand why you don't want this and Second this is a open-source library. you can walk through the code and find the piece of code that makes it. Then change it to what you want. I am now searching for this in this library. As long as I got the answer I reply it. But my guess is that they have used UIApplication.SharedApplication.* to open up Facebook app if it is available.

Sincerely yours,
Peyman Mortazavi

Comment: I had no problem with the facebook app if it worked, but it doesn't. it cames back in my app calling the "DidNotLogin" function from de FBSessionDelegate.

Comment: ok, i added some code.  But i'm sure that the problem is not in my code.

Comment: I did now say that this is your code's fault. I said it is the SDK's fault. so we need to walk through the SDK code (since it is open-source) and find the specific code which applies this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: you'll get the same error if you are in the sandbox and try to logon with a real user.